# Text converted in inkscape produces a shaking hand

Tags: inkscape

Text produced in inkscape produces a shaking hand and  a line through it when being  drawn in video scribe.

Any similar experiences or suggestions please on how to overcome this

Comment: Can you upload an svg example file please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *video scribe*, but this sounds, as if the font is not found by the application. 
If both programs run on the same system, you might need to tell *video scribe* where to find the font.

A second approach is, to convert the text in Inkscape to path, which is a non reversible operation (except by undo, while the program is running, of course). It would be wise to keep a copy of the original text/image, so in case you have to make adjustments at the text.

If *video scribe* only handles text, not paths, this will not work.